# Django - How to properly access reverse relationship ManyToManyField

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

This is my models.py (I'm using the default Django User model as well):

```
class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="userextended_set")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    follow = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="follow_set")
```

Now, to access a list of 'follow' users of a particular user (users which a particular user is following), I'd do something like this:

```
a = User.objects.get(username='a')
a.userextended_set.follow.count()
```

My question is, how do I get a list of users whom a particular user is on the 'follow' list of (i.e. who are following him)? I tried this:

```
# Assuming user 'a' is on the 'follow' list of only one users (i.e.
# assuming .get() will only return one user object).
User.objects.get(username='a').follow_set.get().username
```

but I get an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'UserExtended' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Comment: `User.objects.get(username='a').follow_set.get()` returns a `UserExtended` instance, which doesn't have a `username` field. The `username` field belongs to `User`

Comment: @CésarBustíos Correct. How do I get a list of users whom a particular user is on the 'follow' list of (i.e. who are following him)?

Comment: From a `UserExtended` you can call any QuerySet method -> `a.userextended_set.follow.all()`

Comment: @Gocht Right, but `a.userextended_set.follow.all()` gives me a list of users whom `a` is following (who are on `a`s follow list). What I want access to is a list of users who's follow list `a` is on. How would I be able to access that?

Comment: So you have a user, and you want users this first user is following to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be what you need:

```
user  # this is your user
UserExtended.objects.filter(follow=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
user_ids = UserExtended.objects.filter(follow__username='a') \
                               .values_list('user', flat=True).distinct()
result_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)
```